# Persisted Records in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model, persistence

I have to make a functionality for an "Item" Model. The initial requreiment requirement is :
- The Item should be persisted and reference the user that submitted them.
What exactly means that it should be persisted?
Do I have to use the persisted?(Returns true if the record is persisted, i.e. it’s not a new record and it was not destroyed, otherwise returns false.) function ?

Maybe this is too obvious but I have to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish I had "Ruby/Rails" classes when I was at school..

Yes. You have to define that `Item` `belongs_to` `User`, so that each item will have `user_id` (you'll gave to add this column to `users` table).

Persisted means saved. You can check it as you've mentioned.

You can also go with method in `Item` class:

```
def persisted
  map{ |i| i if i.persisted? }
end
```

or with scope:

```
scope :persisted, -> { where.not(id: nil) }
```

Comment: Thanks andrey  for the instant reply!